# xslt to Replace an xml attribute with another and a value with some other

Tags: xslt

I have an xml in following form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query>
    <queryParams name="accountID">Star TV</queryParams>
    <queryParams name="assetID">Friends</queryParams>
    <queryParams name="accountExtRef">Tata</queryParams>
</query>
```

I need separate xslt to:

1. replace name="providerID" with name="ContentProvider" such that the
   resulting xml becomes:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <query>
       <queryParams name="companyID">Star TV</queryParams>
       <queryParams name="assetID">Friends</queryParams>
       <queryParams name="accountExtRef">Tata</queryParams>
   </query>
   ```
2. replace "Star TV" with Colors such that the XML becomes

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <query>
           <queryParams name="accountID">Colors</queryParams>
           <queryParams name="assetID">Friends</queryParams>
           <queryParams name="accountExtRef">Tata</queryParams>
       </query>
   ```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by simply adding extra templates to the identity transform to match the changes you need.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="queryParams/@name[. = 'accountID']">
      <xsl:attribute name="name">companyID</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="queryParams/text()[. = 'Star TV']">
      <xsl:text>Colors</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<query>
   <queryParams name="companyID">Colors</queryParams>
   <queryParams name="assetID">Friends</queryParams>
   <queryParams name="accountExtRef">Tata</queryParams>
</query>
```

In this case, it does both changes in one go, but it should be clear enough how to split this into two separate XSLTs if required.